# I have a local image and I want to use it in my iOS app, but I want to get the tap areas in the image and then draw the animated route?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, maps, imagemap

I have a local image and I want to use it in my iOS app, but I want to get the tap areas in the image and then draw the animated route?
Also, the route should be shortest.
Attached are the images for better understanding

#### Plain Image

[[image]]

#### After Selecting the location from map

[image]

Comment: for that you need to use SVG file and it will manage every touch point based on your requirement.

Comment: I have used SVG, but when I convert my custom image to SVG it doesn't works perfectly.

Comment: SVG is not a simple image conversion you have to specifiy all points and area to be clickable for that you have to understand SVG formate and based on that you can achieve your expected output. Link1 : http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp
Link2 : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element

Comment: Thanks for your help..Do you think other than SVG, can we also achieve this thing with png?

Comment: Not sure but as per my exprience SVG is the best solution for your requirement.